# New to scheme - Difficulties in writing list

Tags: scheme

I am trying to complete this practice problem in order to get better at scheme, but for the code I have so far it give me a warning saying: "Warning in compile: possible incorrect argument count in call (cons (list (car l1) (car l2))"

I have been looking at this code, and still can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
define (zip l1 l2) 
(if (or (null? l1) (null? l2))
 (cons (list (car l1) (car l2))
   (zip (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))))

(define (map-binary func l1 l2) 
 (map (lambda (l2) (apply func l2)) (zip l1 l2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with the call to `cons`, but you're missing the first opening parenthesis and the base case for the `zip` procedure, which will end the recursion:

```
(define (zip l1 l2) 
  (if (or (null? l1) (null? l2))
      '() ; this was missing
      (cons (list (car l1) (car l2))
            (zip (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))))
```